# Vue app is producing an error in Chrome I cannot find an answer for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to learn Vue in depth and so I started from the beginning of the documentation again and working through it back to front.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Learning Vue</title>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my index.js file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.mount("#app");
```

and here is my App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    {{ count }}
  </button>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const count = ref(0);

function increment() {
  count.value++;
}
</script>
```

In Chrome (Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)) I get the following error and nothing displaying on the page:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of “application/octet-stream”. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I read that if the browser doesn't know what type it is it will respond with "application/octet-stream" but then if you specify the type of the script as module why doesn't the browser know what type it is?

I have really searched as to why I am getting this error but I cannot find an answer. I also looked at many examples and it doesn't seem like there is an error in my code.

Why am I getting this error please and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is serving the file to the browser using an improper `Content-Type` HTTP header - it must be `text/javascript` but the server either sends `application/octet-stream` or does not set this HTTP header at all.

It's your web server which is to blame - not the browser and certainly not Vue. Firefox will give you simiar error.

Comment: Ok thanks so how do I fix this pls? I am using live server on VS Code

Comment: I am not familiar with this live server. But if you switch to Vue CLI - you won't have such a problem. It will serve the files with the proper MIME types.

Comment: I did not change anything I simply restarted the server and now I get a different error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". I normally use Vue CLI but I am trying to understand the very detailed way Vue works so I am starting from scratch and not using a build step

Comment: What do you mean by "not using a build step"? That you're referencing the Vue runtime from a CDN in your HTML file(s) ?

Comment: not using the Vue CLI and simply importing Vue via CDN

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and it's actually fairly obvious but I lack the experience to have seen this from the start.

If you do not use the Vue CLI you cannot name a file .vue because the browser doesn't know what a vue file is. You have to call it .js so for example this doesn't work:

```
    <script type="module">
      import { createApp } from "vue";
      import app from "./app.vue";

      createApp(app).mount("#app");
    </script>
```

but this works fine

```
    <script type="module">
      import { createApp } from "vue";
      import app from "./app.js";

      createApp(app).mount("#app");
    </script>
```

and so we learn everyday.
I do feel however the documentation for vuejs.org can be improved and they can show better examples that are complete code and not just snippets. Beginners need that extra help.

Comment: I have used the Vue CLI most of the time so far but now I want to learn what goes on under the hood. I'm not a complete beginner but still a beginner. Thanks

Comment: Vue 3 officially recommends using Vite, not the CLI.  Quite telling people to use deprecated tools because "you wouldn't understand" @IVOGELOV That's not what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

importmap is suited for development and currently it doesn't have good [support](https://caniuse.com/import-maps).

you can use services like [nexuscode.online](https://nexuscode.online) as development environment without need to worry about this kind of problems.

Comment: Yes I know but I am using Chrome and it's supported and changing to the normal CDN import doesn't change anything.